# how to capture parameter and value from line

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, perl, json

we want to capture only the parameter - `segment.bytes` and his value

example

```
echo "$info" | grep "segment.bytes"
{"version":1,"config":{"segment.bytes":"10737555","retention.bytes":"104857600"}}
```

what I think is to drop all the words until `segment.bytes` and cut the `segment.bytes` include the value without the *double Quotes*

example of expected results

```
echo "$info" | grep "segment.bytes" |  ......

segment.bytes:10737555
```

**I try this**

```
echo "$info" | grep "segment.bytes"   | sed s'/"/ /g' |  sed 's/^.*segment.bytes/segment.bytes/' | awk '{print $1":"$3}
```

**and I get**

```
segment.bytes:10737555
```

but I feel my approach could be dangerous , since the results to get the value is very **sensitive** and important , get wrong results could be **catastrophic**

**I will happy to get other option that are more reliable**

Comment: Why not use `jq`?

Comment: from some internal reasons I can installed it because security issues

Comment: Run it under a restricted user then.

Comment: sorry this isnt option

Comment: @yael Then you need to provide more insight. Can a similar pattern occur on other lines of `$info`? Is the value always a number, or can it contain error-messages if determination of that value failed? If so, what to do? What wrong results could occur? What wrong output must be avoided at all cost?

Comment: In any case, escape the literal `.` in your search regexps as in `\.`, because the `.` otherwise means "any single character".

Comment: it will be better if you post your approach so it will be clear for all

Comment: As I said - please clarify these points. Do we need to ensure only a numerical value can follow `segment.bytes`, or can we trust that the value following always is numerical. Can it be `-1` as an error indicator, or is it always non-negative? This will affect the construction of the regular expression and `awk`/`sed`/ ... commands, so we need to know this.

Comment: segment.bytes will include only -a-z characters , if you asking about

Comment: the value of the parameter - segment.bytes will be only integer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try piping your `$info` variable though this `sed` call:

```
echo "$info" | sed -E '/"segment\.bytes"/s/.*"(segment\.bytes)":"([^"]+)".*/\1:\2/'
```

It will look for a line with the pattern `"segment.bytes"` and extract the `segment.bytes` string and the string in the following parentheses (defined as "anything but `"`" for simplicity) into the capture groups 1 and 2, and print "capture group 1", ":", and "capture group 2".

*(Note that the option to activate extended regular expressions may vary depending on your `sed` version. `-E` is now POSIX standard and works on current GNU, MacOS and BSD `sed`, but if it fails, consult the man page on how to activate ERE)*

**To be more selective, try**

```
sed -E '/"segment\.bytes":"[0-9]+"/s/.*"(segment\.bytes)":"([0-9]+)".*/\1:\2/'
```

which will only accept an integer value, both in the line search and in the value capturing part.

Comment: `-r` is an argument that was used in old versions of only GNU sed to activate EREs. These days both GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed use `-E` (consistent with `grep -E`) for the same functionality so it's more portable (but still won't work in all seds)

Comment: @EdMorton yeah, I keep getting contradicting feedback about that, and the GNU `sed` version I had at hand doesn't even specify `-E` in the manpage. So, I'm sort of lost there ...

Comment: Right, for years `-E` was undocumented for some reason even though it was supported. I'd always use it since it's common to 2 sed versions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `grep` before calling `sed`.

```
$ echo "$info"
foo
{"version":1,"config":{"segment.bytes":"10737555","retention.bytes":"104857600"}}
bar

$ echo "$info" | sed -n 's/.*"\(segment\.bytes\)":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1:\2/p'
segment.bytes:10737555
```

or for a very specific match on that whole line to make the odds of a false match close to impossible but would obviously be more sensitive to changes in the format of the input:

```
$ echo "$info" |
sed -n 's/^{"version":[0-9][0-9]*,"config":{"\(segment\.bytes\)":"\([0-9][0-9]*\)","retention\.bytes":"[0-9][0-9]*"}}$/\1:\2/p'
segment.bytes:10737555
```

The above will work in any sed.

Answer (score 0):

The safe and robust way to go here is the `jq` utility:

```
$ echo "$info" \
| grep -F  '"segment.bytes"' \
| jq  -r '.config | "segment.bytes:" +  ."segment.bytes"'
```

**bash:**

Employing `parameter substitutions` we clip from left and right ends and extract the value of the segment.bytes attribute.

```
name="segment.bytes"
var=${info#*\"${name}\":\"}
printf "%s:%s\n" "$name"  "${var%%\"*}"'
```

Another way to do it is, first carve up tye info string into newlines on  comma and braces, so that grep can then be brought to bear and strip the double quotes from grep's output:

```
$ echo "$info" \
| tr '{,}' '[\n*]' \
| grep '^"segment\.bytes"' \
| tr -d \"
```

Using Perl with the JSON module

```
$ echo "$line" | grep -F  '"segment.bytes"' \
| perl -MJSON -lne '$,=":";
  my $k = "segment.bytes";
  print $k, decode_json($_)->{config}{$k};
'
```

In case JSON module is unavailable you can do this also. Here in this we first generate a valid Perl code using sed and then bring it to life in perl by means of the do statement. Then the json object $j is a hash reference from which we extract the keys we want.

```
$ echo "$info" \
| sed  \
    -e '/"segmen\.bytes"/!d'  \
    -e 'y/:/,/;s/.*/$j=&;/' \
  > ./foo.json 
$ perl -I. -le '$,=":";
  my $name = "segment.bytes";
  do "foo.json" or die $!;
  print $name, $j->{config}{$name};
'
```

The awk and sed are pretty self explanatory

```
$ echo "$info" | grep -F segment.bytes \
| awk -F '"segment\\.bytes":"'  '
  {
    t = $2
    sub(/".*/, "", t)
    $0 = FS t
    gsub(/["\\]/, "")
  }1'
```

```
$ echo "$info" | grep -F segment.bytes \
| sed -ne '
    y/{,}/\n\n\n/
    /^"segment.bytes"/!D
    s/"//g;P
  '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can below awk command

```
echo "$info"|awk -F "," '/segment.bytes/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /segment/){gsub("\"","",$i);print $i }}}'| sed "s/.*{//g"
```

output

```
segment.bytes:10737555
```